# how to copy elements that are in an array but not in another on a third array

Tags: java

i have two arrays filled with random int values.What i want to do is put the elements that are in one of the arrays but not in the other on a third array.How can i do this?

```
int[] array1 = new int[10];
int[] array2 = new int[10];

for(int j=0;j<array2.length;j++){
    int alea = rant.nextInt(10);
    valorpos = alea;
    array1[j] = rant.nextInt(10);
    array2[j] = rant.nextInt(10);
}
```

can anybody help me to continue the code jus to achieve whatever i said,thank you very much
what i want to achieve is:

```
array1:[5,7,9,2,9,8,3,2,4,8];
Array 2: [6,2,5,8,3,0,5,9,2,0];
resultat:[7,4,6,0,0]
```

Comment: i have tried with a double loop between the both arrays and if(array1[i]!=array2[j]){ thirdarray[i]==array[i]; and things like these

Comment: Move it to your question please. The code is not readable in comments.

Comment: Is it that your question is asking, basically, if the number 1 is in array 1, but not in array 2, put it in array 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do here is step back and think about what you're trying to solve.
You have two arrays each with random numbers in, lets say they are something like:

Array **A**:

> 1,3,4,5,6

Array **B**:

> 4,9,4,5,6

So we need to find the the values within array **A** which are *not* in array **B**. How would you work this out on paper? You would start with the first number of array **A** and scan through each number within array **B** to check whether its in there, if it is we stop looking, else we continue to the last number. So for the example above we would find:

Array **Result**:

> 1,3

So lets translate this into some code:

```
// a list which will be used to put the unique values in
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

// loop through each number in the first array
for(int i=0; i< arrayOne.length; i++){

    boolean isInOtherArray = false;
    // check this number against each number in the second array
    for(int j=0; j<arrayTwo.length; j++){

        // if the number matches, then we know its not unique 
        // so we stop the search
        if(arrayOne[i] == arrayTwo[j]){
            isInOtherArray=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // if its not in the other array we know its unique so it goes 
    // in our result list
    if(!isInOtherArray){
        result.add(arrayOne[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: missing a list.toArray()?

Comment: Could certainly add that, but the point of my answer is to try help the user in solving the logic behind the problem @burrito77

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be to use collections to do this. Create a list from the first array and a set from the second. Then remove all elements of the second collection from the first one. Finally, produce an array. Something along the lines:

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.stream(array1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Set<Integer> set2 = Arrays.stream(array2).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
list1.removeAll(set2);
Integer[] array3 = new Integer[list1.size()];
list1.toArray(array3);
```

Comment: There's no way the person understands a line of this code.

Comment: @burrito77 The code is fully described in the answer.

Comment: Sure, to you it makes perfect sense, but to a person who probable doesn't know what a Set or List is, this will definitely confuse them as they won't know HOW this all happens.

Comment: If they don't even know how to find if two numbers are different and if so put them in a new array, then they've got looong way to go before being able to understand this. I'm talking AP Java and our class hasn't even gotten to this after 1.25 semesters!

Comment: @burrito77 This is a correct and quite efficient answer. I'm totally fine if it requires OP some effort to understand it. Most good answers do.

Comment: I don't dispute that this answer works, but just say that it doesn't actually help the person because they don't understand the answer - like if you were a toddler and someone tried to explain to you that a dark room is just the absence of particles moving at a wavelength between 380 and 700 nm, sure, it would be correct, but you wouldn't understand it.

Comment: @burrito77 I disagree. I think it helps more than for-loops over arrays all over again. It is good to learn about collections, it is absolutely not that difficult and here's an example to learn.

Comment: but don't you agree that it's easier to learn for-loops and arrays first and then go learn collections?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a nested for loop? Not the most efficient way but simple enough for your needs...

```
boolean contain;

//loop through the first array
for(int number1 : array1){
    //set contain to false
    contain = false;

    //loop through the second array
    for(int number2 : array2){

        //if number1 in first array equals number2 in second array
        if(number1 == number2){
            //set contain to true and break the loop
            contain = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //if contain is still false
    if(!contain){
        //add number1 to third array...
    }
}
```

Comment: lol good edit did you not write this in a compiler or something

Comment: I'm afraid this does not answer the question.
Your code does not really test for numbers which "are in one of the arrays but not in the other". Which is the whole point of the question.

Comment: @GriffinBender good call, you probably just need to negate the condition and that should fix it, right?

Comment: @burrito77 `number1 != number2` won't fix anything here. It is not a valid condition for "`number1` is not present in `array2`". It only checks if `array2` has some element which is different than `number1`.

Comment: @GriffinBender Better. You can also break the cycle right after `contain = true;`, no need to cycle to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try with two for loops. First loop through the first array and consider each current element, then loop through the second array to check if the `current` number from `array1` is in `array2`. If it is not present in `array2`, then add it to `array3`. Lastly I added a piece of code to trim `array3` to size.

```
    int[] array1=new int[10];
    int[] array2=new int[10];
    int[] array3=new int[10];
    // populate array1 and array2 ....

    boolean isInArray2;
    int current;
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        current = array1[i];
        isInArray2= false;
        for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            if(array2[j] == current) {
                isInArray2= true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!isInArray2) {
            // not in array2 -> must add in array3
            array3[counter] = current;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    // Trim array3 to avoid null values:
    int[] tmp = array3;
    array3=new int[counter];
    for (int i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
        array3[i] =tmp[i];
    }
```